# "NameError: global name is not defined" thrown while PDB considers it defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

I'm trying to debug some code that uses the built in any function, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm able to access the variable using PDB, but once I use it in a generator to the any function, it seems to suddenly be considered undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```
-> src = self['src']
(Pdb) n
-> if any(key not in src for key in self.keys):
(Pdb) p src
{'type': 'local', 'location': '/tmp/tmpy5F3Rz/secrets'}
(Pdb) p type(src)
<type 'dict'>
(Pdb) p self.keys
['location', 'type']
(Pdb) [key not in src for key in self.keys]
[False, False]
(Pdb) n
*** NameError: global name 'src' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you post the entirety of your code?

Comment: I can't post more than what is here on StackOverflow.

Comment: This does work, but I don't know why it makes a difference:

if any([key not in src for key in self.keys]):

Comment: It's really difficult to guess what's actually going on if you're not willing to publish more of your code. Perhaps you can try to distill it into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been the issue:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-January/522224.html

Answer (score 0):

While executing

`if any(key not in src for key in self.keys):` 'key not in src for key in self.keys' argument would be passed to any function as a generator.

**Reasons:-**

1) Generator has its own scope ie. within (key not in src for key in self.keys)

2) Generators is executed lazily refer:- http://naiquevin.github.io/python-generators-and-being-lazy.html

**Possible Solution:-**

Replace the statement with

`if any([key not in src for key in self.keys]):`